# Is there a way to limit the Asset upload directory in Redactor?

Tags: redactor

I am looking to control what asset directories are available from the image upload button in a rich text field. Is this possible?

Also, does anyone know the Redactor setting to set the default size of the editor? I can't seem to track it down.

Thanks!

Comment: Got same problem. Feature request here : http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9335715-limit-the-asset-upload-directory-in-redactor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Is there a way to limit the Asset upload directory in Redactor?**

No. You'll want to use a Matrix Field with an image block.

That said, it's possible you could create a Redactor button that does this via a plugin, but it'd probably be a bit of work.

**Does anyone know the Redactor setting to set the default size of the editor?**

The setting your looking for is `minHeight`.  Here's an example:

```
{
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen', 'pagebreak'],
    minHeight: 200
}
```

A longer discussion on custom Redactor toolbars and a few more examples can be found in this article: [Custom Redactor Toolbars for the Rich Text Field in Craft CMS](http://straightupcraft.com/articles/custom-redactor-toolbars-for-the-rich-text-field-in-craft-cms)

Comment: Hey Ben, this came up as a need for me today. If I were to make a plugin to restrict Redactor uploads to a single folder, what "bit of work" would be necessary?

Comment: Hey @LindseyD.  I do not know! =)  I wasn't referring to any specific knowledge beyond it seems that Craft has integrated uploads to some degree, so it would likely be possible to take that a bit further.  I'd probably start by trying to dig into how Craft is extending Redactor for file uploads as a start.